# How to edit this SQL Server query to be more accurate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'll schedule it from the built in feature in SQL Server 2005 to execute it every 30-35 minutes.
This below is the queries:

```
UPDATE PREMIUM_SERVICE2 SET ndays = ndays - 1 
WHERE strAccountID NOT IN
    (SELECT strAccountID FROM CURRENTUSER) 
    AND ndays > 0 AND (PremStart < DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))
DELETE FROM PREMIUM_SERVICE2 where nDays = 0
```

But there is 1 issue. Once they got the premium from the website it will add it like `10/11/2013 11:50:40 PM` which means every 30 minutes when these 2 queries are executed above it will always `-1` on `nDays` instead of approximately 1 day. So, I thought to add it like that:

```
UPDATE PREMIUM_SERVICE2 SET ndays = ndays - 1, PremStart = GetDate() 
WHERE strAccountID NOT IN
    (SELECT strAccountID FROM CURRENTUSER) 
AND ndays > 0 AND (PremStart < DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))
DELETE FROM PREMIUM_SERVICE2 where nDays = 0
```

So, when its updating, it will also update the `PremStart` but that makes it bad because now it can miss 30 minutes and when they have 30 days premium .. it could add them by mistake at least 1 day which makes it a bit bad since the scheduled job will be executed every 30 minutes. So, how to edit the first query to make sure it will be more accurate and will actually subtract 1 day only when it really passed ? I hope you guys understand what I mean.
I use SQL Server 2005

Comment: You're counting down every day the ndays counter. I'd just track when the premium period started and check that against the current time whenever the premium "feature" is being used. That way you have no ongoing maintenance and perfect accuracy.

Comment: So how to achieve this with my current queries?

Comment: Not at all because you don't need them. This is the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: So mine is currently good to do what I want ??

Comment: No, you cannot do what you want the way you try to. The error is not in your query but in your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are all the attributes used pertaining to the premium period? Just the starting date/time and the number of days left? With the counter ticking once a day that would be enough, but once every 30-35 minutes? At some point, you'd start needing to know whether `nDays` has already been subtracted today or not – you couldn't tell that with just these two columns, and that is the issue.

If it is mandatory that whatever needs to know the number of days left should be reading that value from a dedicated column in a table rather than calculating it every time based on fixed initial values, then you *need* to allocate one more column so that you could get the ending point in one form or another – that is the only way I can imagine that you could track the number of *days* left when running the query *more than once a day.*

For instance, the third column could be the initial length of the premium period. That way you could use the following statement to update `ndays`:

```
UPDATE PREMIUM_SERVICE2
SET ndays = TotalDays - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PremStart, GETDATE()) / 1440
WHERE strAccountID NOT IN
    (SELECT strAccountID FROM CURRENTUSER) 
    AND ndays > 0
;
```

where `TotalDays` is the third column's name. As you can see, `ndays` is not simply decremented – it is calculated at every run.

That is actually what your application (or whatever is requiring the `ndays` value) could do instead of pulling a pre-calculated value, i.e. you could put that expression in the query that is used to request the number of days left, and thus get rid of `ndays`. Naturally, you would also need to modify the DELETE statement, replacing the `ndays` condition with one that uses the same expression as above, or one similar to it, to check which rows should be deleted.

I am not saying that `ndays` is absolutely not needed, though. There *can* be value to having it, and there may well be sense in allocating it in your particular case, but then you do need to remember the ending point in some form.

There is one more potential issue to address, arising primarily from the new way of calculation of `ndays`. If the job running the script gets delayed for some reason (stopped for a time, then resumed), that might theoretically result in negative `ndays` values and so a DELETE statement using such condition as `ndays = 0` condition is bound to miss them. Therefore, I would just change the condition to `ndays <=0`.

Comment: Great explanation. I really appreciate it. Just I've got a few questions if possible. So, if you checked my second query example in the main post you'll see that I thought if the ndays is update, it will also update the PremStart, so next time it will update it will be again after 1 day has passed. Isn't that basically doing the same thing as you've suggested but in another way? Also, if I use your method and they purchase again it will add them +30 days, so they will have for example 60 .. wouldn't this make problem ? Please let me know if you see my second query example. I will appreciate.

Comment: I thought I wouldn't comment on your second query because you yourself already thought it bad. :) I didn't like it for a somewhat different reason, though: you are rewriting `PremStart` and are thus losing information about the exact starting date/time. Perhaps that information is not really important in your situation, but personally I would rarely consider such an approach (never as the first solution, certainly).  But yes, that approach is equivalent to what I'm suggesting in that it indeed updates `ndays` once a day (potentially giving you up to almost 30 minutes extra premium time). …

Comment: As for adding more premium time on top of one that's still pending, I believe you could just increment `TotalDays` by the added days  without changing `PremStart`. With my suggestion, the `ndays` value would update correspondingly at the nearest invocation of the job, for it would be calculated anew. It would look e.g. like this: starting date `10/1/2013`, length `30`, last calculated `ndays` value `16`, you add `30` to the length (`TotalDays`) making it `60`, `PremStart` remains the same, at the job's next iteration `ndays` becomes `46` (or `45` depending on the actual time it is executed).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer just need to know, so both ways will potentially give up to around 30 minutes extra premium time, right ?

Comment: Correct. As it happens, your other method may not be so bad for you after all. In fact, it has the benefit of using fewer columns than my suggestion. I myself am still uncomfortable about the idea of rewriting both columns, but I guess if there's no need to keep the original values, it should be all right. If you stay with your own method, you might want to consider posting that as a self-answer (and accepting it too), by the way.

Comment: Ahh, nope. You helped me a lot, so I will accept it. Just last thing .. I prefer to use my own one but just need to tweak the `DELETE` statement to be instead of `= 0` but `<= 0` to make sure it deletes all 0 and - minus values, right?

Comment: That wouldn't harm it, although I'm scratching my head in search of a single situation that would lead to a negative `ndays` with your approach and just can't find any. Anyway, changing it to `<= 0` certainly feels like being on the safe side. :)